# Importing collection type using ImpEX Import

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have a data structure as follows defined in my items.xml file:

An itemtype of Country type having a attribute(name as collection type of another itemtype Region,which has an attribute(name=locality)of another itemtype say Locality. What would be the right option for ImpEx import to insert some Localities and Countries?We were trying a script like :

INSERT_UPDATE Country;code;regions(locality(code))

;abc;1,2

Comment: Have you encountered any errors while running the above impex, or do you just want to find a better way of the above script?

Comment: @dj_frunza,I am getting errors in execution of the scripts like this,so just wanted to confirm if this is the right way and what to do if locality has more attributes to be imported.

Comment: please add the errors you receive to the question so that it can be easy to find the  problem

Comment: @dj_frunza,Does the script sound to be correct in a generic sense

Answer (score 0):

Separate Country from Region from locality you would write something like :

```
INSERT_UPDATE Locality;code
;locality_1
;locality_2
;locality_3

INSERT_UPDATE Region;code;locality(code)
;1;locality_1
;2;locality_2
;3;locality_3

INSERT_UPDATE Country;code;regions(code)
;c_1;1,2,3
```